# Unique Event names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just tried to `bind` and `trigger` `isDisabled` event on input element.

But got an error in IE8. Because specific `isDisabled` event already exists http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533902(v=vs.85).aspx

How do I make unique event names and keep them readable?

Is there a better way then using something like `thisNodeWasDisabled` ?

Comment: Could you append the element ID (or whatever you're using as your selector) to your event name to provide better odds of randomness?

Comment: there can be elements without ID, so no ID

Comment: `myEvents.isDisabled` looks too complicated

Answer (score 1):

Use a [namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) like myEvents e.g. `isDisabled.myEvents`(the namespace is the second part)